# Android App not discoverable by name or keywords?

Tags: android, discovery

I was wondering If I could get some help on this. I have created a new mobile app and published it to the android market a few days ago. I was naturally expecting to be able to find the app by simply searching for its name in the Play Store, however when I do this nothing shows up for my app and I can only find the app by searching for the package name.

I just want to know if this is something I am doing wrong or just the way the Play Store works? A link to my app is below:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skystalker.wedcon&hl=en_GB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that I'm able to locate your app by searching (160-ish result). However your app name seems to be a common one, and that's causing it to go down the list since it's new and haven't yet gained popularity. If you care about the app coming up first in the search either: change the name to a unique one, or get popular (more downloads and high ratings).